# Why would one split HKDF output into multiple parts instead of expanding it multiple times

Tags: keys, key-derivation, hkdf

Reading the [implementation details of Signal's](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) approach on [double ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm) algorithm I noticed the following key derivation procedure for using AES-CBC with HMAC:

> HKDF is used (...) to generate 80 bytes of output.
>   (...) HKDF info is set to an application-specific byte sequence
>   distinct from other uses of HKDF in the application. The HKDF output
>   is divided into a 32-byte encryption key, a 32-byte authentication
>   key, and a 16-byte IV.

So the following is proposed

```
HKDF-Extract(salt, mk) -> PRK
HKDF-Expand(PRK, 'distinct_info', 80) -> OKM
```

**What is the advantage over expanding `PRK` 3 times for IV, AES-Key and MAC-Key by using the info parameter?** e.g

```
HKDF-Extract(salt, mk) -> PRK
HKDF-Expand(PRK, 'distinct_info_iv', 16) -> IV
HKDF-Expand(PRK, 'distinct_info_aes', 32) -> AES Key
HKDF-Expand(PRK, 'distinct_info_mac', 32) -> MAC Key
```

The only thing I see is that the former approach is *slightly* more efficient by doing only a single expand (e.g. only 1 HMAC = 2 hashes) instead of 3. On the other side, as far as I understand HKDF, expanding multiple keys from the PRK is exactly the point of the 2-step approach and is also clearer to read and understand for developers who are less familiar with implementing security relevant protocols.